# Informatica Powercenter One to Many SQ Query and Mapping Issues

Tags: informatica

I have multiple VIEWs where the PERSON_VIEW to a PHONE_VIEW has a one to many relationship. In the following query, I got TOAD to correctly output the result into 1 row for each person record.

I am having a problem getting it to work with Informatica Powercenter. I copied/pasted the query to SQ SQL Query section.

Since the query takes the PHONE_NUMBER and check against the PHONE_TYPE on whether it is of type HOME, BUSINESS, or PERSONAL, it output 3 phone number columns called HOME, BUSINESS, and PERSONAL.

I created 3 new columns in the SQ Ports called HOME, BUSINESS, and PERSONAL to match the query output columns. When I validate the query, it constantly says it must match 28 ports from the SQ. When I just add 1 column and map to Exp Transformation and then to the Target, it still give this error. I counted the ports and it is 29. If I removed the phone columns, it works and the count is 28. When I add just one phone column, it gives the error.

I think I am missing a step.

Any help is appreciated.

PERSON VIEW
1  John M. Doe

PHONE VIEW

1 111-111-1111 HOME
1 222-222-2222 BUSINESS
1 333-333-3333 WORK

TOAD Result
1 John M. Doe  111-111-1111 222-222-2222 333-333-3333

Here is the QUERY (This works in TOAD)

```
SELECT PERSON.PERSON_ID, 
       PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
       PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME,
       PERSON.LAST_NAME,
       PHONE.HOME,
       PHONE.BUSINESS,
       PHONE.PERSONAL,
       PHONE_TYPE
FROM PERSON_VIEW PERSON
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT PERSON_ID, PHONE_TYPE,PHONE_NUMBER 
                           FROM PHONE_VIEW)
                           PIVOT
                           (
                             MAX(PHONE_NUMBER) 
                             FOR PHONE_TYPE  in ('HOME' AS HOME,'PERSONAL' AS        PERSONAL , 'BUSINESS' AS BUSINESS)

                           )

)PHONE ON PHONE.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
```

Comment: I am not very clear about your problem but whatever i understood is - you  are expecting one record PERSON_ID having three columns viz. phone_home, phone_business, phone_personal ? Since your phone table has multiple records for one person you would get duplicates. Use  sorter + aggregator + expression combination to aggregate three records into one record having three columns. Then you can join with person table and you should get unique records.

Comment: I revised the problem description. I am trying to figure out how to configure the Powercenter SQ section to handle new columns from the query result.

Comment: You can add a column in SQ. And in override section, use your SQL that is working in Toad. Only remember SQL sequence and data type should match.

Comment: Hi Koushik, I have 28 columns before the Add, In the SQ, I added HOME, BUSINESS, and PERSONAL columns. I dragged the HOME, BUSINESS, and PERSONAL columns from SQ to the Exp Transformation and then to the Target. Thus I have 31 columns connected but it still giving me the error that "Query should return exactly 28 fields..." I added the 3 fields in the SELECT and GROUPBY. After the dragged the 3 new columns, the number should be 31 not 28. Again, any help is appreciated esp for your time.

Comment: Can you please check if you have any session level override? Have you refreshed the session after your change? If not, then modify session override and refresh session. Make sure 31 columns connected from source to expression through SQ. Criteria should be - number, sequence and data type of SQ should match with the SQL query output. if you still face any issue, can you please post a screenshot of your source qualifier.